# Is it possible to mount an amazon fsx to an amazon workspace?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-workspaces, amazon-fsx

I am trying to mount an amazon fsx to my amazon workspace but im having some trouble. When I follow the documentation using the command prompt to type

`net use Z: \\insert_amazon_workspace\share`

I get
`System error 53 has occurred`
and
`The network path was not found`

Does anyone know why this could be? Is it because I am using a workspace or is it an entirely different problem all together. Either way, any ideas on how to solve this?

Thanks

Comment: https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/desktop-and-application-streaming/using-amazon-fsx-for-windows-file-server-with-amazon-workspaces/

Answer (score 0):

This might be happening because of 3 reasons:

1. You have not joined your instance to the same domain on which the FSx exists. (Its better if you use an AWS Manaded AD rather then your own set up on AWS, just my opinion this way we have less anomalies)
2. You have not Set up the proper Firewall Rules in your respective VPC group for the particular FSx. read docs to learn more about this.
3. The particular instance that you trying to get joined with FSx has limited inbound rules and does not allow communication from this FSx drive or vice versa.

Kindly check all these possibilities, pretty sure it will be one of these.